I can't see my laptop internal hard disk during installation of windows
I am trying to install windows 11 on my current laptop.
It runs linux on one partition while I want to allocate the other partition to windows.
I have created a bootable USB on my flash drive using Rufus.
But during the installation, I entered the advanced option to install windows in the other partition, but I can't find my laptop disk there.
what can be the issue and the solution.

Try one of these solutions:

Don't select "Install Now", choose "Repair your computer", troubleshoot, command prompt, write setupprep.exe, enter the activation key, select the empty partition, and go on to install the OS.

You can write diskpart in the command prompt to reformat the empty partition:



diskpart
lis dis
sel dis 0 # Make sure to select the right disk
lis par
sel par 1 # Make sure to select the right partition
format quick fs=ntfs label=win-11
assign letter=w
exit


reboot and try the normal installation.

You can use dism apply-image command to install the OS directly from install.wim file. this is an example:


Dism /apply-image /imagefile:X:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:C:\

BCDboot C:\Windows /s C: /f ALL


The first and third way requires a menu entry in the Grub boot menu like this one:
menuentry "Windows 11" --class windows11  {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntldr
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    ntldr /bootmgr
}

Make sure to replace set root='hd0,msdos3' with the appropriate value based on your Windows partition.

where can I get the activation key?
